# What counts as a token for bpemb's encode_ids_with_eos()

Tags: nlp, rnn, tokenization

I have probelms understanding bpemb's `encode_ids_with_eos()` or similar.
When I run the following code i get none-word like segmentations (rather syllalbus based or letters grouped of two in a seemingly arbitrary fashin). But how is that useful? And how is it useful when assigning ids?

```
print(bpemb_en.encode_ids_with_eos([" , ", ". "]))
print(bpemb_en.encode_ids([" , ", ".   "] ))
print(bpemb_en.encode_with_eos([" , ", ".   "] ))
print(bpemb_en.encode_with_eos(["Canvas and grouped People", ".   "] ))
print(bpemb_en.encode_with_eos(["Canvas and grouped people", ".   ", "I went to China to eat a roll of meat", "I am just an ordinary person"] ))
print(bpemb_en.encode_ids_with_bos_eos(["Olla , ", ".   ", "_"]))
print(bpemb_en.encode_with_bos_eos(["Olla , ", ".   ", "_"]))
print(bpemb_en.encode_with_bos_eos(["<PAD>", "Olla , ", ".   ", "_"]))


OUTPUT:
[[912, 934, 2], [896, 2]]
[[912, 934], [896]]
[['▁', ',', '</s>'], ['▁.', '</s>']]
[['▁can', 'v', 'as', '▁and', '▁group', 'ed', '▁people', '</s>'], ['▁.', '</s>']]
[['▁can', 'v', 'as', '▁and', '▁group', 'ed', '▁people', '</s>'], ['▁.', '</s>'], ['▁i', '▁w', 'ent', '▁to', '▁ch', 'ina', '▁to', '▁e', 'at', '▁a', '▁ro', 'l', 'l', '▁of', '▁me', 'at', '</s>'], ['▁i', '▁am', '▁j', 'ust', '▁an', '▁or', 'd', 'in', 'ary', '▁pers', 'on', '</s>']]
[[1, 13, 922, 922, 914, 912, 934, 2], [1, 896, 2], [1, 912, 976, 2]]
[['<s>', '▁o', 'l', 'l', 'a', '▁', ',', '</s>'], ['<s>', '▁.', '</s>'], ['<s>', '▁', '_', '</s>']]
[['<s>', '▁', '<', 'p', 'ad', '>', '</s>'], ['<s>', '▁o', 'l', 'l', 'a', '▁', ',', '</s>'], ['<s>', '▁.', '</s>'], ['<s>', '▁', '_', '</s>']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way the sentences are grouped in seemingly arbitrary tokens is based on the vocabularay size of the bpemb when instantiated/initialized. They represent the byte-paring that are the most frequent.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEikzVL-lZU for an explanatory tutorial.